# Rspec/Rails 4: Failure/Error: visit "/todos" NoMethodError: undefined method `todos' for nil:NilClass in rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

Failed to make my test pass. Can someone pointme  what am missing.
I am testing the index page of the todos(which is single page application).

Error Log:

```
1) Displaying todos should display the list of todos
 Failure/Error: visit "/todos"
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `todos' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/controllers/todos_controller.rb:6:in `index'
 # ./spec/features/todos/index_spec.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

todos_controller.rb

```
 class TodosController < ApplicationController

skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

 def index
 @todos_completed_today = current_user.todos.where(is_completed: true).
 where("updated_at  >= ?", (Time.zone.now - 24.hours)).order('todos.position ASC')

 @todos = current_user.todos.where(is_completed: false).order('todos.position ASC'
 end

 def create
  @todo = current_user.todos.new(todo_params)
  @todo.save
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to todos_path }
    format.js
  end
 end

 def edit
  @todo = current_user.todos.find_by_id(params[:id])
 end

 def update
  @todo = current_user.todos.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @todo.update_attributes(todo_params)
 end
```

Here is my todo index spec.
features/todos/index_spec.rb

```
 describe "Displaying todos", :js => true do
   let(:todo) { FactoryGirl.create(:todo)}

    it "should display the list of todos" do

      visit "/todos"

     expect(Todo.count).to eq(0)
    page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'Todos')


    fill_in "title", with: "MyString"
    click_button "Create"

   expect(page).to have_content("Todo has been created!")
   expect(todo.todo_title).to eq(title)

  todo.reload!
  expect(Todo.count).to eq(1)
  expect(todo.title).eq("Mystring")
 end
```

factories/todo.rb

```
# Read about factories at https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl

  FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :todo do
    title "MyString"
    description "MyText"
    is_completed false
    position 1
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

spec/support/devise.rb

```
module FeatureMacros
  def login_user_in_feature
    Warden.test_reset!
    Warden.test_mode!
    user = create(:user)
    login_as user, :scope => :user
    user.confirmed_at = Time.now
    user.confirm!
    user.save
    user
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :view
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
  config.include FeatureMacros
end
```

In factories/user.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    #your user factory
  end
end
```

In factories/todo.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :todo do
    title "MyString"
    description "MyText"
    is_completed false
    position 1
    user{User.last}
  end
end
```

In features/todos/index_spec.rb

```
feature "Displaying todos", :js => true do
  scenario "should display the list of todos" do
    login_user_in_feature
    todo = FactoryGirl.create(:todo)
    visit "/todos"
    expect(Todo.count).to eq(0)
    page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'Todos')
    fill_in "title", with: "MyString"
    click_button "Create"
    expect(page).to have_content("Todo has been created!")
    expect(todo.todo_title).to eq(title)
    todo.reload!
    expect(Todo.count).to eq(1)
    expect(todo.title).eq("Mystring")
  end
end
```

If it did not work or have anything, please tell me, you can see the authentication for the user using FeatureMacros because current_user won't work without it

Comment: I am testing this without any authetication. I skipped the authentication part for some reason.

Now  I could go to localhost:3000/todos

Comment: current_user will be nil in this case, Also you should create a factory for Todo

Comment: Hany Elsioufy, Yes  I created factory for todo and also added this line in the index_spec.rb file. 
      let(:todo) { FactoryGirl.create(:todo)}

Comment: I will be grateful if you could paste the updates in factories.rb along with  features/todos/index_spec.rb

Comment: Please see my code again. I just edited and added the factory/todo.rb file as well. Thanks!

Comment: Todo belongs to user, create a factory for user, and you should indicate that this todo belongs to the user you created, I will edit my post including the answer

Comment: Please check the edited post, I updated some other things as well, check again

Comment: it should be feature scenario not describe it